# Querying ElasticSearch using a JSON file through JAVA API

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I have a query in valid JSON format which works well in kibana or Sense when I use GET request.I am also able to create this query using XContentBuilder, but I need to send this query using its JSON form as it is to ElasticSearch. Is it possible to store the query in a JSON file and query ElasticSearch using this JSON file.

My query -

```
{
  "min_score":5,
  "sort" : [
    {
      "_geo_distance" : {
        "location" : [40.715, -73.988],
        "order" : "asc",
        "unit" : "km",
        "mode" : "min",
        "distance_type" : "arc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "hospital",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "50000km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 40.715,
            "lon": -73.988
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to store this query in a JSON file and use this JSON file to send a search request directly without using Query builder.

Comment: This is not well supported by the offical ES API: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/search-elasticsearch-with-java-client-using-json-query/74329

Comment: Yeah, it was possible in the earlier versions, but the current version of ES does not support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a search template, and store this template in the cluster state, see the [official documentation about search templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-template.html), especially about pre-registered templates.

Comment: Yeah, Search templates can be used to send this json query directly to elastic search.